# How can I plot a sympy function with the dependant variable on log scale?

Tags: python, logging, plot, sympy

I want to plot a function in sympy with the dependent variable on log
scale. However, it don’t get it to work.

For the linear plot it works nicely:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym

x = sym.symbols('x')
sym.plotting.plot(sym.log(x), xlim = (0.1, 10), xscale = 'linear')
```

[image]

However, the plot on log-scale doesn’t work:

```py
sym.plotting.plot(sym.log(x), xlim = (0.1, 10), xscale = 'log')
```

[image]

I don’t understand why. I read the
[documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html) and
did some research on google, but couldn’t find the solution.

`sym.plotting.plot` is based on matplotlib I figure - maybe there is a
matplotlib workaround to get the x-axis on log scale?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

With your `plot` command you are plotting `log(x)` for `x in [-10, 10]` (the default range, because you didn't specify one), then zooming into the x-axis such that `x in [0.1, 10]` is visible (that's what you are asking with `xlim`).

When you request a log plot, the plotting module discretizes the x-range with Numpy's [`geomspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html). As mentioned above, the default range goes from `-10` to `10`. Look what happens when the starting value of the x-range is negative:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.geomspace(-10, 10, 5)
print(x)
# array([-10.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  10.])
```

Then, the plotting module evaluates `log(x)` to get `array([nan,  nan,  nan,  nan, 2.30258509])`, which ends up with an empty plot.

To get to the desired results, you need to specify the range of the plot, like this:

```py
plot(log(x), (x, 0.1, 10), xscale = 'log')
```

[image]